# How is this menu icon created only with CSS?

Tags: css

It appears that the before and after selectors are used to create 3 span elements.

The confusing part is that there is only one actual span in the html.  How are the other 2 spans, actually created.

Here is the HTML/CSS.

**HTML**

```
<a class='mobile_menu_icon'>
  <span></span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.mobile_menu_icon span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.mobile_menu_icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.mobile_menu_icon span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-250%);
    transform: translateY(-250%);
}
.mobile_menu_icon span:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    top: 0;
}
.mobile_menu_icon span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(250%);
    transform: translateY(250%);
}
.mobile_menu_icon span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Its now a good choice to render a menu icon with css. Use an icon instead:)

Comment: If you look closely then the first row is of `::before`, second is of `<span>` itself and last one is of `::after`.

Comment: it is created with pseudo elements https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:after` and `:before` create pseduo-elements which are children of the targeted element.

They are created by CSS and are unique in this manner.

You should be able to see them in the DOM under their parent element as `:after` and `:before`.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have one  mentioned in Html, you have added :before and :after in your CSS.

So, other 2 line (before and after) is added through CSS. with :before and :after

Pseudo element (:before) which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML)

Refer this for more info : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

-------------------------- More on this -------------------------

The content that is inserted is not visible in the page’s source. It’s visible only in the CSS.
Also, the inserted element is by default an inline element (or, in HTML5 terms, in the category of text-level semantics). So, to give the inserted element a height, padding, margins and so forth, you’ll usually have to define it explicitly as a block-level element.

Refer this : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/#characteristics-of-inserted-content

Comment: There is no child elements. All are Pseudo elements. If you remove the content:" " from the css, they won't appear.

Comment: Generally, if you are adding it before or after they can't be a child of this <span>... As it is added independently but with the reference of <span>... Maybe Pseudo elements is the more suitable... but this is arguable.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are only one span in your HTML and in your DOM. But **:after** and **:before** creates pseudo-elements dinamically by css.

But the css of your fiddle have some things that doesn't make much sense:

- The class **".mobile_menu_icon span"** and **".mobile_menu_icon"** get the same element.
- And the selectors **".mobile_menu_icon span:before"** and **".mobile_menu_icon span:after"** are repeated.

I've created a fork of your fiddle with a simplification of your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rk52ke5q/2/

```
.mobile_menu_icon span {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;  
}

.mobile_menu_icon span:before {
    transform: translateY(-250%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    content: '';
}

.mobile_menu_icon span:after {
    transform: translateY(250%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    content: '';
}
```

Note that the after and before selectors have

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

That means they will have the exactly same size of their "real" element (the span). And the final trick is the

```
transform: translateY(250%);
```

That moves your "pseudo span" down.

If you add a "hover" in the selector you will see the magic happen when you pass the mouse through the "real" span: http://jsfiddle.net/pnt7uez1/1/

Comment: They don't have a "type" because they are just a custom content added by css that doesn't really exists in the DOM.

Comment: Since you can add only "caracters" in the content like `content: "Your text here";` maybe they are just a "plain string" in the DOM. I don't know. If you are a brave man you can go further and try to debug the [webkit](https://www.webkit.org/building/debug.html) and tell to us how it behaves :P

Comment: You can also supply images to the pseudo-element's `content` property: `content: url(path/to/img.png);` or simply use an empty string for the `content` and supply a `background-image`.

Comment: @cadegalt the second example shows the other two lines when you mouse over the span

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element in the firbug and you will see pseudo class that is `:after :before` which are responsible to create the other two lines.you can read it here [pseudo classess](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)
the top line is created by

```
.mobile_menu_icon span:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    top: 0;
}
```

the bottome line is created by

```
.mobile_menu_icon span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    top: 0;
}
```